# Validate file or folder exist using javascript

Tags: javascript

Want to check file exist or not. I want to perform some action if file is not exist. Please find my code as below

```
<form id ="TestForm">
Pathname <input type="text" id="PathName" readonly="readonly" />
<input type="button" value="Select Name" onclick="SelectName('POST')" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var popup;
function SelectName(methodType) {       
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('HEAD', "C:\new.txt", false);
        xhr.send();

        if (xhr.status == "404") {
         popup = window.open("Popup.jsp", "Popup", "width=300,height=100");        
        popup.focus();
        }        

  }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you forget to include the code with your question, perchance?

Comment: I have added code now